# Smartcard (EAP) authencation for L2TP/IPsec VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, smartcard, l2tp

I have a certificate in a smartcard that I use to connect over a VPN on Windows.

The VPN is a L2TP/IPsec, and uses EAP for authentication.

I tried multiple connection methods, some using UI (Network Manager), others using StrongSwan:

**Network Manager**

The only option that let me use a smartcard is IPSec/IKEV2. It fails with a "no proposal chosen error". When I enable custom proposals and add IKE as aes256-sha1-modp1024 and ESP as aes256-sha1, the syslog says it authenticates, but then it times out.

**StrongSwan**

I used the following links as reference:

1. https://www.strongswan.org/docs/readme4.htm#section_8.1
2. https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SmartCards

Here is the added connection I created on /etc/ipsec.conf

```
conn aa
        left=%defaultroute
        keyexchange=ike
        leftsourceip=%config
        #leftcert=%smartcard:0
        leftid=myid@server.com
        leftfirewall=yes
        right=server.com
        keyexchange=ikev2
        ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048
        esp=aes128-aes256-sha1-sha256-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128-sha1,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256
        auto=add
```

I also configured /etc/ipsec.secrets and /etc/strongswan.d/charon/pkcs11.conf

When I try to execute the following command:

> sudo ipsec up aa

I get this result:

```
initiating IKE_SA aa[1] to <server>
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 10.228.65.143[500] to <server>[500] (1312 bytes)
received packet: from <server>[500] to 10.228.65.143[500] (320 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) ]
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
authentication of 'myid@server.com' (myself) with RSA signature successful
establishing CHILD_SA aa{1}
generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH CPRQ(ADDR DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 10.228.65.143[4500] to <server>[4500] (780 bytes)
received packet: from <server>[4500] to 10.228.65.143[4500] (76 bytes)
parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error
establishing connection 'aa' failed
```

**Troubleshooting info**

IKE Scan (https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues)

> $ sudo ./ike-scan.sh server | grep SA=
>
> SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=MD5 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=RSA_Sig LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x0000708
>   SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=RSA_Sig LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
>   SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=128 Hash=SHA1 Group=19 Auth=RSA_Sig LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
>   SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=256 Hash=SHA1 Group=20 Auth=RSA_Sig LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)

**Edit**

When using leftauth=eap-tls and after installign the root certificate at /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts, the error is:

```
parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
received end entity cert "CN=<server>"
received issuer cert "DC=..."
  using certificate "CN=<server>"
  using untrusted intermediate certificate "DC=.."
checking certificate status of "CN=<server>"
  fetching crl from 'http://anotherserver.crl' ...
libcurl request failed [28]: Resolving timed out after 10521 milliseconds
crl fetching failed
  fetching crl from 'ldap:///CN=...' ...
LDAP bind to 'ldap:///CN=..' failed: Can't contact LDAP server
crl fetching failed
certificate status is not available
  reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 1
authentication of 'CN=...' with RSA signature successful
constraint check failed: identity '<server>' required 
selected peer config 'aa' inacceptable: constraint checking failed
```

Comment: The server didn't send a certificate request, so the client won't send its certificate, by default. Try adding  _leftsendcert=always_ to force that.

Comment: Now a new line saying "sending end entity cert" with the certificate used for authentication showed up, but the error is still the same

Comment: If possible, check the log on the responder. Maybe it expects EAP-TLS authentication (you could try that if you have the _eap-tls_ plugin installed by setting _leftauth=eap-tls_).

Comment: Just edited my question with the results

Comment: To fix this, configure the actual identity via _rightid="CN=..."_. You can also disable the CRL fetching in the settings of the _revocation_ plugin (or disable the plugin) to avoid the timeout.

Comment: I used right=<server> and righid=rightid=%any and now I got an error saying: "server certificate does not match to 'CN=<otherserver>'"

Comment: If that is not related to EAP-TLS (in which case _aaa_identity_ might help) then that's a serious misconfiguration on the server.